# HARBOR Registry Return x509 error During the login session

Tags: x509, harbor

In ethernet connected system I use harbor registry for docker images in login session it returns x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead error.
How I resolve this certification problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate your Harbor certificate, the previous maybe
generated by Common Name, use the SAN field to sign the certificate, https://goharbor.io/docs/2.5.0/install-config/configure-https/